# Getting route param as null in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7, routeparams

I am unable to retrive the route param as null. I am using angular7.
Please find the code below

**HeaderComponent ts file**

```
    import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
             this.getNewsSelectedFromRouteParam();
        }
    getNewsSelectedFromRouteParam() {
            alert();
            let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('typeId');
            alert(id);
        }
getNewsByCountry(newsTypeSelected: any) {
        this.router.navigate(['/news',newsTypeSelected]);
        this.getNewsSelectedFromRouteParam();
    }
```

**Header html**

```
<div class=" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                XXX
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div *ngFor="let cr of country" class="dropdown-item"
                    (click)="getNewsByCountry(cr.value)" >{{cr.name}}</div>
            </div>
```

**app routing  ts file**

```
 const routes: Routes = [
        { path: 'news/:typeId', component: XxxComponent },
    { path: '**', component: XxxComponent }
    ];
```

Comment: what do u mean by retrieving as null ?

Comment: instead of  root param value getting null but i am able to see the change in url.

Comment: Since you are taking the snapshot value, it wont dynamically change. You will have to subscribe to get changing typeId values

Comment: You have the <router-outlet></router-outlet> in your main app.html?
I once forgot to use it and I couldn't find the reason why I dont get the params.

Comment: @Talg123 you saved me hours! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to get that Params in "HeaderComponent ts" where it should call from "XxxComponent". I added that route param code in XxxComponent ts file now working as expected. I am able to get the route params.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did? The route wasn't accessible in the sub-component or?

Comment: After find a lot of answer on StackOverFlow, this answer is the only solve my problem

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways of accessing a route parameter.

1. Statically (One time when page loaded)
2. Dynamically (Gets updated if param is changed within your app without reloading page by browser)

You can get more reference here: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot

See following snippet for implementation:

```js
let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.typeId; // any param name after "params"
```

or

```js
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
    let id = params.get('typeId');
});
```

> Make sure you are using above code when component is initialized i.e. in or after ngOnInit().

Comment: I am getting id as"undefined" . I logged params, it showing as empty JSON.  Any thoughts on why it is getting empty?

Comment: You should call it in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.id
```

to get the query parameters shared by all the routes

Answer (score 0):

You call getNewsByCountry in (click), probably cr.value is null, what is cr.value? Is the ID?